# Sortable is not a function Jquery UI

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

When I tried to add sortable feature to a table I got this error. This project is an Asp.net Mvc project.

I don't know why i am getting this error. When I do it in VS code as a clean just frontend environment I dont get this error even though I use the same includes. But in Visual Studio Asp.net mvc project there might be more than one jquery includes. But I don't know how to detect and solve. This project is developed by someone else. And I am requested to add sortable ui feature.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRWaL.png)

[script include](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYhuo.png)

[browser network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09sdu.png)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6aYy.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the follow code.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable > tbody").sortable();
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

```css
#sortable {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
}

#sortable td {
  margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  height: 18px;
}

#sortable td span {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1.3em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table id="sortable">
  <tr>
    <td class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</table>
```

https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

> Note: In order to sort table rows, the tbody must be made sortable, not the table.